# Get object hit when searching array in Elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, search, elasticsearch, json, java

I am trying to get an object out of a JSON array that is stored in elasticsearch.  The layout is like this:

```
[
   object{}
   object{}
   object{}
]
```

What I need for when I do a search and it hits on one of these objects, to get the specific object it matches to.  Currently, using the java API I am searching with:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
 .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("text", "pottery").boost(5) 
 .minimumShouldMatch("1"));



            SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("stuff")
                            .setTypes("things")
                            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                            .setQuery(qb)
                            .setPostFilter(filter)//.setHighlighterQuery(qb)
                            .addField("places.numbers")
                            .addField("name")
                            .addField("city")
                            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true) 
                            .execute()
                            .actionGet();
```

But this will just return the whole object that I hit or when I tell it to return the field "places.numbers" it will only return the first object in the "palces" array, not the one that was matched in the query.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. I would probably do it with a [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) and [inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html), given what you've shown in your question, but it could also probably be done with the [parent/child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html).

Here is an example with nested docs. I set up a simple index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "parent_doc": {
         "properties": {
            "parent_name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "nested_docs": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "nested_name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added a couple of simple documents:

```
POST /test_index/parent_doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"parent_name":"p1","nested_docs":[{"nested_name":"n1"},{"nested_name":"n2"}]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"parent_name":"p2","nested_docs":[{"nested_name":"n3"},{"nested_name":"n4"}]}
```

And now I can search like this, using `"inner_hits"`:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "nested_docs",
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "nested_docs.nested_name": "n3"
            }
         },
         "inner_hits" : {}
      }
   }
}
```

which returns:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 2.098612,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "parent_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 2.098612,
            "_source": {
               "parent_name": "p2",
               "nested_docs": [
                  {
                     "nested_name": "n3"
                  },
                  {
                     "nested_name": "n4"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "inner_hits": {
               "nested_docs": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 1,
                     "max_score": 2.098612,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "test_index",
                           "_type": "parent_doc",
                           "_id": "2",
                           "_nested": {
                              "field": "nested_docs",
                              "offset": 0
                           },
                           "_score": 2.098612,
                           "_source": {
                              "nested_name": "n3"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/ef7debf436fec2a10097ba2106d5ff30ff8d7c77

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, it definitely looks like that would work, but Is there another way without the parent/child relationship? We were hoping to avoid that due to the nature of our data, sorry I failed to mention that in the original post!

Comment: I didn't use the parent/child relationship in my answer, I used nested docs.

Comment: Isn't your mapping and POST using a parent doc? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Well, I named it that, but the name is arbitrary. You might want to read up on [nested docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html).